# Nuxt signing up user returns Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am trying to signup or login as a user from my Nuxt app to an API that works perfectly. I keep getting `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` and I don't know why I keep getting this error.
I also get `unknown action type: authenticateUser`

I previously made a post request from the signup page and it works but because I am trying to save some things to the store i moved the axios request to the store.

below is my code
On the signup page, on clicking the signup calls the `createAccount` method

```
data() {
    return {
      isSignup: true,
      form: {
        email: null,
        fullname: null,
        password: null
      }
    }
},
methods: {
    createAccount() {
      this.$store.dispatch("authenticateUser", {
        isSignup: this.isSignup,
        form: this.form
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.$router.push('/loginsuccess')
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e))
    }
  }
```

and in my `store/profile.js` file, which is set up as a store module

```
export const mutations = {
    setToken(state, token) {
        state.token = token
    },
    logIn(state) {
        state.loggedin = true
    }
}

export const actions = {
    async authenticateUser(vuexContext, authData) {
        let authUrl = 'https://lookaam.herokuapp.com/signup/'
        if (authdata.isLogin) {
            authUrl = 'https://lookaam.herokuapp.com/login/'
        }

        return await this.$axios
        .$post(authUrl, authData.form)
        .then(result => {
            const token = result.data.token
            vuexContext.commit('setToken', token)
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e))
    },
}
```

and in my `nuxt.config.js` file, I have

```
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
  ],

  axios: {
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL,
    Credentials: false 
  },
```

when I click the signup button, almost immediately on the console I get both `unknown action type: authenticateUser` and `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` as if it never even communicated to the api.

Please what can be the issue?

Comment: You're always looking for trouble mixing `await` and `then`. Better to `await` the value of the first promise, then `await` the value of the second (if there is one), then return the result. Or return the promise chain, returning the inner promises as well (e.g., if `commit` returns a promise, `return` that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createAccount()` is dispatching the action without the appropriate namespace (`"profile"` for `store/profile.js`), and `this.$store.dispatch()` returns `undefined` if the action is unknown, leading to the error you observed.

To fix the issue, use the `profile` namespace in the dispatch:

```js
this.$store.dispatch("profile/authenticateUser").then(...)
```

Also note the [`$` shortcuts](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage#-shortcuts) resolves to the **response data** instead of the [`axios.Response` instance](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema). That is, in your `authenticateUser` action, `this.$axios.$post()` resolves to the `token` itself:

```js
export const actions = {
  async authenticateUser(vuexContext, authData) {
    //...
    return await this.$axios
      .$post(authUrl, authData.form)
              
      .then(token => {
         vuexContext.commit('setToken', token)
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e))
  },
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-axios-action)

Answer (score 1):

I think that enchaining multiple `then` will not work, but you could achieve your desired behavior by watching the `loggedin` state then redirect to the url if it's true :

```
data() {
    return {
      isSignup: true,
      form: {
        email: null,
        fullname: null,
        password: null
      }
    }
},
computed:{
  isLoggedn(){
    return this.$store.state.loggedin;
  }
},
watch:{
  isLoggedin(newVal){
   if(newVal){
       this.$router.push('/loginsuccess')
    }
  }
},
methods: {
    createAccount() {
      this.$store.dispatch("authenticateUser", {
        isSignup: this.isSignup,
        form: this.form
      })
    }
  }
```